# How to use ST_DWithin to find near point?

Tags: sql, gis, postgis

This is the first time I create a GIS query. In one table of my database, there is a column with point type. Each record is one ATM machine. I want to write a query to get ATM machines that near by my location within 1km range.How to use  ST_DWithin in SQL query to find record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM atm_finder
  WHERE ST_Distance(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT([Lon] [Lat])',4326),26986),ST_Transform(location,26986)) <= 1000
```

Where [Lon] & [Lat] - GPS coordinates of the point. But so far as you used POINT type at first use:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('atm_finder', 'location', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
```

Of course before that you should rename the field 'location' (in order to not lose the data) and fill the new one with this data.

Comment: I don't understand some number: 4326, 26986. What do these mean?

Comment: You should read the PostGIS documentation and about geo-projections altogether.
*4326* is WGS84 projection (used in Google Maps for example; it's GPS per se)
*46986* is the metric projection. You need to convert one to another to make any collateral operations.
Also you may read about *SRID* - this is right the numbers.

Comment: I re-created a table with geometry column use point type. I insert record successfully. But when I query like you suggest I get error: "transform: couldn't project point (2.19832e+007 1.15841e+008 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)". What do I have to do?

Comment: Sorry, friend. I've made a mistake in the last parameter of AddGeometryColumn. You need to use "2" (dimensions - Lon & Lat). Repeat the whole procedure and try again. There mustn't be any troubles. When you make new geometry column, test it with `SELECT ST_GeomFromText(location) FROM atm_finder`. So you'll see if the previous actions were made correctly.

Comment: I also saw your mistake when I re-created table yesterday. I test successfully with ST_GeomFromText but I haven't yet fix the error in my previous post.

Comment: This whole code works fine:
`CREATE TABLE atm_finder (id integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT atm_finder_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('atm_finder', 'location', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
INSERT INTO atm_finder (id, location) VALUES
(1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-117.157305 32.715738)', 4326)),
(2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-117.15046 32.715793)', 4326)),
(3, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-117.130204 32.726624)', 4326));
SELECT id
FROM atm_finder
WHERE ST_Distance(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-117.147605 32.715802)',4326),26986), ST_Transform(location,26986)) <= 1000;`
And don't forget push + :)

Comment: I'm gald to hear it!
Don't forget accept answers with interface and add likes, it's important for community :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see well how ST_DWithin could be used with two points...

Something like that .

```
select atm.id
from atm_finder atm
where ST_Distance(<your location>, atm.location) <= 1000 

//1000 = meters, works fine with geography types
//have to check your projection with geometry types
```

The way your table is created looks strange to me, by the way...

Comment: I set location as type point. When i run a query with your suggestion, i get error: "column location.the_geom does not exist"

Comment: Please show your database structure. the_geom is just a current way to call the "geometry/geography" column in a table.

Comment: this is the statement to create my table:
CREATE TABLE atm_finder
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  location point NOT NULL,
  serving_hour text NOT NULL,
  address text NOT NULL,
  num_machine integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT atm_finder_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)

Comment: see edit, then. How did you create your table ? With this script ? Or with a visual tool ?

Comment: I create by visual tool, the above code is generated automatic. Run your code, i get error: function st_distance(geometry, point) does not exist

Comment: could you show me the result of a few rows when doing "Select location from atm_finder" ?

Comment: `st_distance(geometry, point)`
That's because you use POINT type of column instead of GEOMETRY.

Comment: How can I change the type of location to GEOMETRY and use?